# cant give the borader space and print a word on it

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I need to design a web page that should be look like the above page.

I finished the auto viewer, but I found that I can't print a word above the slideshow (1/6 & autoviewer). How can I print it out?

Also, I try the code and it still can't print the word out, here is the code

```css
<style type="text/css">

#myslideshow {
  border-spacing:10px 10px;
  border-left:7px solid black;
  border-right:4px solid black;
  position:relative
}

#myslideshow > div.overlay-one {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right:10px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:18px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

#myslideshow > div.overlay-two {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right:10px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  background:rgba(56,56,56,0.5);
  padding:3px 6px;
  border-radius:3px;
}
</style>

<div style="float:right;width:500px;>
  <div "id="myslideshow">
    <div class="overlay-one">1/6</div>
    <div class="overlay-two">AUTOVIEWER</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It only apply the border space of the left and the top of the photo - it mean there are not blank between border and the photo in the right and bottom
How to fix it?

Comment: by creating a live demo here on SO, and we'll fix it for you.

Answer (score 0):

u haven't mentioned HTML 
so here it is

```css
#slideshow{
  background: #fff url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/sTX8qbOtPN8/hqdefault.jpg");
  width: 480px;
  height: 360px;
  position:relative;
}
#slideshow>div.overlay-one{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right:10px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:18px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
#slideshow>div.overlay-two{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right:10px;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  background:rgba(56,56,56,0.5);
  padding:3px 6px;
  border-radius:3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
<div class="overlay-one">
1/6
</div>
<div class="overlay-two">
AUTOVIEWER
</div>
</div>
```

It's all about position:  add parent with relative and child with absolute and you are done.